# How do I get the PID of a UWP hosted app?

Tags: api, process, windows-10, vb6

I am iterating through all windows.

I find a window with the following name: "Groove-Musik".
It has the hwnd 1111.

I want to know its process name / PID.

When I look at it in Taskmanager, I see the following:

[image]

I right-click them item and select "Details", and I see the following:

[image]

Now I try to do the same by code.

I use the following:

```
Dim ProcID&
GetWindowThreadProcessId(1111, ProcID)
```

The ProcID is not 8028.

Instead, it returns a proc id of the following process:

[image]

It is the same with all the UWP hosted apps like Calculator, Groove, Photos, Movies. The taskmanager points to Music.UI.exe, Video.UI.exe, but my code always points to this stupid ApplicationFrameHost.exe.

How could I get the correct PID / what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Edit: According to a suggestion I have now tried the following:
I have ran "EnumChildWindows" on hwnd 1111.

The result is:

```
window hwnd: 1111
window text: "Groove-Musik"
window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 22216
    ----------------
    childwindow #1
    child window hwnd: 0
    child window classname: ""
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 22216
    ----------------
    childwindow #2
    child window hwnd: 196874
    child window classname: "ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow"
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 22216
    ----------------
    childwindow #3
    child window hwnd: 197220
    child window classname: "ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow"
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 22216
    ----------------
    childwindow #4
    child window hwnd: 131488
    child window classname: "ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow"
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 22216
```

I was requested to post the results for calc.exe.
Here they are, but I want to point out that at this point, its process is not suspended.

[image]

And this is the detail view when I click the calculator app:

[image]

```
window hwnd: 202848
window text: "Rechner"
window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 16500
    ----------------
    childwindow #1
    child window hwnd: 0
    child window classname: ""
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "[system process]", PID: 0
    ----------------
    childwindow #2
    child window hwnd: 201864
    child window classname: "ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow"
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 16500
    ----------------
    childwindow #3
    child window hwnd: 398148
    child window classname: "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow"
    child window text: "Rechner"
    child window process: "calculator.exe", PID: 17600
    ----------------
    childwindow #4
    child window hwnd: 201862
    child window classname: "ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow"
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 16500
    ----------------
    childwindow #5
    child window hwnd: 464044
    child window classname: "ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow"
    child window text: ""
    child window process: "applicationframehost.exe", PID: 16500
```

By request here is how I get the initial window:

```
' The desktop is the highest window
hw = GetDesktopWindow()
' It's first child is the 1st top level window
hw = GetWindow(hw, GW_CHILD)
' Now load all top level windows

Do
    lCaptionLen = GetWindowTextLength(hw)
    sCaption = VBA.Space(lCaptionLen + 1)
    lCaptionLen = GetWindowText(hw, sCaption, lCaptionLen + 1)
    
    'Some initial checks if the window is visible to the user
    'like IsVisible(hw), IsWindow(hw), etc

    hw = GetWindow(hw, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    
Loop While hw <> 0
```

Comment: Are you using VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: @StayOnTarget I'm using both, both give the same result.

Comment: Well, it just means this window's process *is* ApplicationFrameHost.exe. Try to search for a child window of this hwnd that has a "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow" class name. Then do a GetWindowThreadProcessId on this child. This should get you the process you're after.

Comment: @SimonMourier You mean I should run EnumChildWindows on the main window of the process "ApplicationFrameHost.exe" (in my screenshots, PID 22216)? Or should I run EnumChildWindows on the hwnd 1111? (I have edited my post and have given the hwnd a number to be able to clarify things at discussion).

Comment: Do an EnumChildWindows of the window you initially found: 1111

Comment: @SimonMourier I did that, and I have added the results to my posting.

Comment: Can you try with Windows Calculator? (calc.exe)

Comment: I will in 5 minutes.

Comment: @SimonMourier Is calc.exe suspended for you? I have started it, and it was therefore not suspended, and I got its child window "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow". However, I think that if the process is suspended, you will not have this window. I am not sure yet when Windows will suspend calc.exe, so I wanted to point this out already.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to get the initial window?

Comment: I have added it. i just go through all windows on the desktop and sort many of them out because they are not visible anyways.

Comment: It wasn't clear in your initial question / title you were exclusively looking for a suspended app windows. I think it's normal you don't find an HWND for a suspended process, resources are freed by Windows https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/04/28/the-lifecycle-of-a-uwp-app/ The question now is what exactly to you want to do in the first place?

Comment: @SimonMourier I do find hwnds for suspended processes. That is my problem. I just wanted to point out that for some reason, calc.exe is not yet suspended, and therefore you do see the child window "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow". However, once is it suspended, this child window will be gone. Instead of looking at calc.exe, I would like you to look at your TaskManager and see if you spot any suspended processes (for me it's "Groove Music") and have a look at this instead of a not-yet-supended processs. I think you want to follow along with my explanations, but with calc.exe, you can't.

Comment: Please look at the taskamanger and see if you can spot an application showing the green leaf. It indicates suspended processes.

Comment: Calculator (calculator.exe) and Groove Music (Music.UI.exe) have the same behavior, they are packaged apps. When they are minimized/suspended, their associated process have 3 child windows, including a "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow" class window, otherwise, only have 2 child windows (MSCTFIME UI and IME). There's nothing around that.